# Why this shows error while installing any packages?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, jsx, npm-package

Whenever I install any package with this command

> npm install

then output comes with errors,Here You can See
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/1duiK.jpg)

Comment: Your question is not clear, could you explain more details about errors? witch command do you use, and what is the raised error?

Comment: i use npm install to install react-router-dom and it shows the error desc in image, so what i do to fix this error?@ElyasDolatabadi

Comment: please post text, not screenshots. a tip to make this easier is to redirect command output to a file: `npm install > output.txt`, then you can copy the content in output.txt to paste here

Comment: posting screenshots will usually result in a question getting downvoted and being left unanswered

Comment: Some of your dependencies are known to have vulnerabilities. If you need further help, please make sure to share your `package.json` (at least `dependencies` and `devDependencies`) to have a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

You're not actually getting any errors from `npm install`! It looks like npm is detecting that you've already installed all of the required packages, which is why it just says `up to date`.

However, you see that it is also reporting about some security vulnerabilities or out-of-date dependencies that could be updated. This is normal. You don't have to do anything to get your app to work, but running `npm audit fix` and then manually fixing the remaining dependency errors will result in a more secure dependency tree.